# BeanUtilsBeans copyProperties not copying any fields

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-beanutils

I am trying to use Apache Commons [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/index.html) to copy fields from a source object to a destination object. However, when testing my code, the properties are not copied at all. Following is the code I am using

```java
public class CopyUtilTest {

    public void copySourceToDestination(Object destinationObject, Object sourceObject) throws ApiException {
        BeanUtilsBean beanUtil = new BeanUtilsBean();
        try {
            beanUtil.copyProperties(destinationObject, sourceObject);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new ApiException("Error in copying properties using [NullAwarePropertyCopy]");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testCopy() throws ApiException {
        A source = new A();
        source.setA("John");
        source.setB(23);

        B target = new B();

        copySourceToDestination(target, source);
        System.out.println(target.getA()+" "+target.getB());
    }

}

@Getter
@Setter
class A {
    String a;
    int b;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class B {
    String a;
    int b;
}
```

The output I get when running this test in Junit is `null 0` which clearly indicates that the fields have not been copied. Why could this be happening?

Comment: Can you try using the BeanUtils straight away instead of the bean? Remember that is a static method so you should call it like `BeanUtils.copyProperties(destinationObject, sourceObject);`

Comment: @SantiBarbat I think you are referring to the BeanUtils class from spring. The one I am using is from apache-commons

Comment: I know and see you are creating an instance of a bean and then running copyProperties. Try to import the BeanUtils from Apache commons and call it statically